# Debug on subselection / LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, left-join, subquery

I'm working on this query on mySQL - it seems to be processed on a website with PEAR and MDB2 on the running server (dont know why… din't do that myself). On my local test system it generates always MDB2 error. PHPmyadmin doesn't do this query as well. 
The Subselection is needed because there are not just one but four subselects in this query.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.orderID 
    IN 
        (
        SELECT * 
            FROM table1 
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON (table1.customID = table2.customID) 
        WHERE table1.active=1
        )
```

I can simplify it like that (works):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.orderID 
    IN (1,2,3)
```

The Subselect works, too:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON (table1.customID = table2.customID) 
WHERE table1.active=1
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The inner query should return exactly one column, like:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 
WHERE   table1.orderID IN 
        (
        SELECT  orderId

--              ^^ here

        FROM    table1 
        LEFT JOIN
                table2
        ON      table1.customID = table2.customID
        WHERE   table1.active=1
        )
```